# UITextField inside a UIView thats animated on touch dismisses the view and shows the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a structure for my UIView object and have form elements within it. I run the application and the program is in such a way that when i click a button inside the UIView, it moves the current frame upwards. But thats not the problem.

My phonenumberfield is of type UITextField which is inside a UIView and that UIView is a part of the parent View. I have one button called submit and a segment control on the Parent UIView. But when i touch the phonenumberfield or any textfield type on the parent view, the parent view gets dismissed and keyboard shows up. Its weird I cant understand what the problem is because can't debug this. :(

Comment: maybe more code, or pictures, or your view structure,

Comment: Suggestion use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) for building forms and etc.

Comment: I have the following structure - UIView(Parent)->CustomView(SubView)->View(to create border effect around textfield)->View->UITextField. Now i have all controls working within the CustomView, except for textfield and textarea. The keyboard opens but dismisses the CustomView

Comment: Some code that you use for moving the views up and down too please

Comment: I cant post the code, stackoverflow isnt allowing me :( . Btw i got it working. I seemed to have an issue with my constraints blocking the scroll :) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with the constraints for Auto Layout I had set for my scrollview and managed to fix the constraint and my view started scroll. To animate the view, I set a constant height from the top of the parent view and animated the view by changing the constant which did not affect the keyboard anymore.